# Send param in URL using OFBiz

Tags: freemarker, ofbiz

I want to end a param in URL in OFBiz, but I get this error 
from security

```
org.apache.ofbiz.webapp.event.EventHandlerException: Found URL parameter [twCompagneDeRecrutementId] 
passed to secure (https) request-map with uri [showCompagne] with an event that calls service [showCompagne]; 
this is not allowed for security reasons! The data should be encrypted by making it part of the request body (a form field) instead of the request URL. 
Moreover it would be kind if you could create a Jira sub-task of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-2330 (check before if a sub-task for this error does not exist). If you are not sure how to create a Jira issue please have a look before at http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/JIB2
```

This is my ftl

```
<#if listCompagne??>

            <#list listCompagne as newCompagne>

            <div style="display:flex; width:100%;">
                         <div style="padding:6px; width:24%;"><label>${newCompagne.nom}</label></div> 
                         <div style="padding:6px; width:24%;"><label>${newCompagne.dateDebut ?date}</label></div> 
                         <div style="padding:6px; width:24%;"><label>${newCompagne.dateFin ?date}</label></div>
                         <input type="hidden" value="${newCompagne.twCompagneDeRecrutementId}"/> 
     <div style="padding:6px; width:20%;"> <a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block " href="<@ofbizUrl>showCompagne?twCompagneDeRecrutementId=${newCompagne.twCompagneDeRecrutementId}</@ofbizUrl>">afficher</a>
</div>  



           </div>  
           </#list>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the solution is to go to url.properties and change parameters.url.encrypt to no

Comment: For securiy reason (the reason the error message popups) I don"t recommend to "change parameters.url.encrypt to no"

Comment: how i can do that.

Comment: I think I answered you above, quoting myself:

<<As suggested in the error message, there are plenty examples at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-2330. Just look for one done for a Freemarker template >>

Answer (score 1):

I don't use ofbiz , but you should send parameter in body instead of in query.

In your case I would add a form and submit it using hidden form input, form should be unique per iteration using `index`

```
 <form action="<@ofbizUrl>showCompagne?</@ofbizUrl>" id="afficher${newCompagne?index}" method="post" style="display: none;">
 <input type="hidden" name="twCompagneDeRecrutementId" value="${newCompagne.twCompagneDeRecrutementId}" />
  </form>
 <a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block " 
 href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:
document.getElementById('afficher${newCompagne?index}').submit()">afficher</a>
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. As sugested in the error message, there are plenty examples at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-2330. Just look for one done for a Freemarker template